# ¿Cómo enviar correctamente un objeto matplotlib.figure.Figure a un canal privado de Telegram en Python3 a través de la API de Telegram?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, revisión-de-código, plot, telegram-bot

Sucede que tengo una df llamada `df_trading_pair_date_time_index` la cual contiene la siguiente data:

```
                         Open      High       Low     Close                End Date
Start Date                                                                         
2022-08-12 00:25:00  23834.13  23909.27  23830.00  23877.62 2022-08-12 00:29:59.999
2022-08-12 00:30:00  23877.62  23968.52  23877.62  23936.89 2022-08-12 00:34:59.999
2022-08-12 00:35:00  23936.89  23989.95  23915.92  23962.50 2022-08-12 00:39:59.999
2022-08-12 00:40:00  23960.64  23985.03  23935.60  23966.71 2022-08-12 00:44:59.999
2022-08-12 00:45:00  23966.71  23996.94  23958.00  23983.68 2022-08-12 00:49:59.999
2022-08-12 00:50:00  23982.53  24009.67  23958.89  23996.59 2022-08-12 00:54:59.999
2022-08-12 00:55:00  23995.49  24005.30  23963.92  23964.37 2022-08-12 00:59:59.999
2022-08-12 01:00:00  23965.31  24000.00  23940.61  23975.64 2022-08-12 01:04:59.999
2022-08-12 01:05:00  23977.04  23996.85  23928.95  23943.09 2022-08-12 01:09:59.999
2022-08-12 01:10:00  23944.05  23972.86  23885.00  23905.23 2022-08-12 01:14:59.999
2022-08-12 01:15:00  23905.23  23944.66  23901.74  23925.72 2022-08-12 01:19:59.999
2022-08-12 01:20:00  23925.72  23951.21  23917.84  23945.03 2022-08-12 01:24:59.999
2022-08-12 01:25:00  23945.03  23961.78  23935.12  23945.60 2022-08-12 01:29:59.999
2022-08-12 01:30:00  23945.60  23949.86  23919.90  23934.50 2022-08-12 01:34:59.999
2022-08-12 01:35:00  23934.49  23934.50  23853.65  23895.44 2022-08-12 01:39:59.999
2022-08-12 01:40:00  23895.44  23932.11  23894.67  23906.00 2022-08-12 01:44:59.999
2022-08-12 01:45:00  23905.42  23927.26  23878.57  23902.75 2022-08-12 01:49:59.999
2022-08-12 01:50:00  23902.76  23915.00  23888.08  23889.19 2022-08-12 01:54:59.999
```

Al ejecutar `df_trading_pair_date_time_index.dtypes` la siguiente salida se presenta:

```
Open               float64
High               float64
Low                float64
Close              float64
End Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Y al ejecutar `df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index` la siguiente salida es retornada:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-08-12 00:25:00', '2022-08-12 00:30:00', '2022-08-12 00:35:00', '2022-08-12 00:40:00', '2022-08-12 00:45:00', '2022-08-12 00:50:00', '2022-08-12 00:55:00', '2022-08-12 01:00:00',
               '2022-08-12 01:05:00', '2022-08-12 01:10:00', '2022-08-12 01:15:00', '2022-08-12 01:20:00', '2022-08-12 01:25:00', '2022-08-12 01:30:00', '2022-08-12 01:35:00', '2022-08-12 01:40:00',
               '2022-08-12 01:45:00', '2022-08-12 01:50:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Start Date', freq=None)
```

Con el fin de graficar los datos de mi df, creé el siguiente código:

```
import requests
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
btc_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                            figratio=(10, 6),
                            type="candle",
                            style=s,
                            tight_layout=True,
                            datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                            ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                            returnfig=True)
# Add Title
axlist[0].set_title("BTC/USDT - 5m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy' )
```

Después de ejecutarlo y escribir `btc_plot` en la consola para su ejecución, la siguiente gráfica es retornada:

[image: chart]

Y finalmente al ejecutar `type(btc_plot)` la siguiente salida es retornada:

```
matplotlib.figure.Figure
```

### El problema:

Estoy embalado tratanto de hacer una "simple" cosa, quiero enviar la gráfica almacenada en `btc_plot` a un canal privado de Telegram usando la API de Telegram con Python3, y según [esta sección](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) de la documentación de dicha API, la siguiente línea debería funcionar:

```
requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_str}/sendPhoto',
                          data = {'chat_id':f'-100{channel_id_str}', 'photo': btc_plot, 'caption':'Fue detectada una señal bajista en el par BTC/USDT!'})
```

Sin embargo, después de ejecutar esa línea, lo único que obtuve fue un `<Response [400]>` como salida sin ninguna otra explicación ni excepción por parte de la consola.

Yo creo que puede estar sucediendo porque estoy intentando enviar un objeto `matplotlib.figure.Figure`, pero erróneamente pensé que la variable `btc_plot` había almacenado un objeto `png` debido a que una imagen era devuelta al ejecutar `btc_plot` en la consola, entonces estoy perdido.

Irónicamente, la siguiente línea de código funciona como se esperaría con un `<Response [200]>` como salida:

```
requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_str}/sendMessage',
                              data = {'chat_id':f'-100{channel_id_str}', 'text': 'Fue detectada una señal bajista en el par BTC/USDT!'})
```

[image: wtf]

Honestamente no sé cómo solucionarlo, ¿puedo obtener alguna retroalimentación que mejore mi solución o quizá una alternativa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una alternativa, la cual en realidad creo que siempre fue la forma correcta de hacer lo que deseaba:

```
import telegram

btc_plot.savefig('signal.png',dpi=300, bbox_inches = "tight")
telegram.Bot(token= token_str).send_photo(chat_id= chat_id_str,
                                          photo=open("signal.png", 'rb'),
                                          caption="Fue detectada una señal bajista en el par BTC/USDT!")
```

**Output:**

[image: solución]